# The type or namespace name 'MvvmValidation' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

SO I Have the following problem when trying to built an Xamarin.Forms project. 
[image]
What i have tried so far :

1. Clean solution -> Rebuilt
2. Remove MvvmValidation nugget package and reinstall it
3. Remove Manage Package from VS and Reinstall it

I'm clueless now on what should I do to make it work. An other coworked got the same git branch and it compiles. It's something with my VS but have no idea what.

[image]
[image]

As you can see from picture 2 and 3 the namespace is found.

Comment: Did you add the package to all of your projects in your solution?

Comment: @Demitrian why should i do this. This is a Nugget i want for this specific project and the error is in this project not in othe others.

Comment: looks like a .net framework error. If your library is a different .net framework to the one its referencing it throws this error

Comment: it's a nuget package it's not a custom library. https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmValidation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for my was an update to Visual Studio (had to update to VS 2015 Update 3) . After the update it compiles ok.

Comment: Facing the same problem in Visual Studio for Mac, in Xamarin Studio it works fine on the other hand. Issue opened... https://github.com/pglazkov/MvvmValidation/issues/13

Answer (score 1):

gonna go out on a limb and say this is for **WPF** not **Xamarin.Forms**, matter in fact it doesn't even specify x-plat in its description.

https://github.com/pglazkov/MvvmValidation/releases  - very specific on what it will work with in the release docs.

Comment: as i was saying it has nothing to do with MvvmValidation module itself. It works on my co-worker machine. It's something with VisualStudio, but I have no idea what.

Comment: #if directive missing?

Comment: In img3 i have the directive added. What am i missing?

Comment: At a loss, suggest you sit next to your co-worker and look at what is different.  The package is being interpreted by compiler and Xamarin assemblies which it is not compatible with. Something is very different with yours vs. his/hers project, or VS setup.  Img3 is so tightly snipped that you can't see the #if directive.

Comment: already fixed it, it was the VS Version. Why it didn't compile on my version, no idea.